# Cannot get notification icon to appear for Thunderbird

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird, icons

I am using Mozilla Thunderbird 52.5.0 32-bit on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. An envelope icon used to appear in the Windows Task Tray when a new email came in, and remain there until I looked at new emails. It has stopped, and I have been unable to get it started again.

The popup notification does still work, along with the sound that plays, but the icon in the task tray does not.

I looked at the configuration of the task tray icons; that one is set to "notifications only".

I have searched through some help forums; there is a Thunderbird setting having to do with using IMAP 'status' (Tools / Options / General / open config editor / yes I'll take the risk / mail.imap.use_status_for_biff) that was true and I set it to false. I've restarted Thunderbird, then restarted the Windows machine, and changing that setting seems to have had no effect.

Is there anything else I could do to get my icon back? I'm often away from the computer, it is very helpful to know that an email has come in without having to be at the screen when it does.